# Springboot webflux/webclient call restApi for a list in sequential order

Tags: spring-boot, rxjs, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

In webclient, How can I call for each element of list but in a sequential order. For example in below code I have list of values and I want to call apiA or B for each element of list but in a sequential order. Do I have to use block on api calls?

```
            for(String value : values) {
                if (value.startsWith("A")) {
                    api.callApiA(value);
                } else {
                    api.callApiB(value);
                }
            }
            
            public Mono<String> callApiA(String value) {
                //Calling rest api
                return Mono<String>
            }
            
            public Mono<String> callApiB(String value) {
                //Calling rest api
                return Mono<String>
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concatMap` to

> Transform the elements emitted by this Flux asynchronously into Publishers,... sequentially and preserving order using concatenation.

```
Flux.fromIterable(values)
        .concatMap(value -> {
            if (value.startsWith("A")) {
                api.callApiA(value);
            } else {
                api.callApiB(value);
            }
        })
```